# Image isn't showing in Image and ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my ASP.NET Web forms application I am trying to set an image in UserDP folder to two controls - Image and ImageButton.
Although it seems the URL of the image is correct, image is not being displayed on both controls. I tested the URL by browsing to it in chrome. Also it works with data URI but not with location. I'm assigning image to the control in page load. I was a bit confused by how image URLs are assigned in web forms that's why I almost always used Server.MapPath on trial-error. But now I am stuck.

As requested, here's the behind code:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("UserDP\\14.jpeg");
```

**Edit**: Sorry everyone, I forgot about this question because I moved to some other stuff and now I don't even remember the markup. Anyway thank you for helping out.

This was an ASP.NET Web Forms application, in which I was trying to show image.
I fixed it using solution mentioned by @JennyOReilly

Comment: Please post your markup (HTML).

Comment: Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("UserDP\14.jpeg");

Comment: Use slash "/" instead of backslash "\"

Comment: I meant to type double backslash.

Comment: @tdragon tried slash, not working. Any other help? Thanks

Comment: As @Jenny O'Reilly wrote - post your markup. It might also depend on page and image location on the disc. Try maybe `Server.MapPath("\\UserDP\\14.jpeg");`

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Sorry I forgot about this question because then I moved to some other stuff. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the physical path to the specified location.

In HTML you need to specify URLs and not physical paths.

**Example (wrong):**

```
<img src="C:\temp\UserDP\14.jpeg" />
```

**Example (correct):**

```
<img src="UserDP/14.jpeg" />
```

**To solve your problem:**

Remove `Server.MapPath` and use the following string for `ImageUrl`:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/UserDP/14.jpeg";
```

ASP.NET will automatically replace the `~` with your application's base URL, because `Image1` is a server control. This should work, if your UserDP folder is located on the first level within your application's directory.

Comment: sorry for replying this late. Thanks for the help. It worked. I tried your idea and it had been my habit to use MapPath for every other file operation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: [Image.ImageUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

Use the ImageUrl property to specify the URL of an image to display in the Image control

so you have to type in url address (absolute/full address or relative address);

eg. full address:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "http://localhost:5000/myApp/Content/Images/14.jpeg");
```

eg. relative address:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "Content/Images/14.jpeg");
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I'm new user here which is why I can't up vote yet.