# ImageUrl not finding images in project folder

Tags: c#, html, webforms

I want to create a website which will store 2 images in the "home" page, which will lead to 2 different pages. In the case, I'm using the Image object from the toolbox. When I'm trying to assign the ImageUrl, it don't appear to find anything at all, regardless of the format. I've tried with multiple photos, different folders, there's the result:

[image]

I've also tried to change it programatically in C#, not working, as well:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = @"Images/left.jpg";
```

Should I use the usual `<img src=""/>` for finding images? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on that image shown and choose "include in project" and then try to give imageUrl

Comment: You're the real MVP! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your path value contains the appropriate path from the ImageFiles directory, then you should be able to use the following :

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='~/ImageFiles/<%# Eval("path")%>' />
```

or use the integrated string formatting of the Eval method as shown here :

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("path", "~/ImageFiles/{0}") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code behind you could do something like below including application base URL some thing like below-

> Image1.ImageUrl = @"~/Images/left.jpg"

Please refer the below discussion for more information -

[Image isn't showing in Image and ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235534/image-isnt-showing-in-image-and-imagebutton)

> ASP.NET will automatically replace the ~ with your application's base
>   URL, because Image1 is a server control